# How to get the value of CSS style using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I'd like to know what type of method should I use to get the value of CSS style. I want to set it to jQuery so that I can create conditions to match on CSS "left" value.

Here is the CSS and HTML tag with the style attributes.

```
<div class="items" style="left: -900px"> <span>some content here</span> </div>
```

Here is my jQuery code to get the value.

```
<script>
  var n = $("items").css("left");
  if(n == -900){
    $(".items span").fadeOut("slow");
  }
</script>
```

Is this method correct? It is not working in my end.

Note: left value was dynamic, and it was changing to these value: -900px, -1800px, -2700px, -3600px, -4500px...

Comment: Do u want the value of the attribute, OR the actual position?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I doubt css understands `left` by itself.  You need to use it specifying position.  You are using `.css()` correctly

```
position: relative/absolute/whatever;
left: 900px;
```

heres a fiddle of it working

https://jsfiddle.net/gFLZe/

and without the position here's what you get

https://jsfiddle.net/gkkm5/

Change your if statement to be like this - with quotes around `-900px`

```
var n = $("items").css("left");

if(n == '-900px'){
    $(".items span").fadeOut("slow");
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gFLZe/1/

Comment: Yes, actually the position itself are already coded at the plugin i am using.. although i have to customize the output to make each content have different visual.

Answer (score 4):

You code is correct. replace items with .items as below

```
<script>
  var n = $(".items").css("left");
  if(n == -900){
    $(".items span").fadeOut("slow");
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you're right. With the `css()` method you can retrieve the desired css value stored in the DOM. You can read more about this at: https://api.jquery.com/css/

But if you want to get its position you can check [offset()](https://api.jquery.com/offset/) and [position()](https://api.jquery.com/position/) methods to get it's position.

Comment: No. His mistake was writing "items", which is searching for the *tag* times, instead of writing ".items" which would capture the class *items*.

All the difference lies in the dot.